# Is it possible to use extract-struct-info outside a macro?

Tags: racket

Consider the following racket code to get a list of [`accessor`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html?q=syntax-local#%28tech._accessor%29)s of a given struct:

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/parse racket/struct-info racket/list))

(struct point [x y])

;; get the list of accessors from a struct
;; ex. (get point) = '(point-x point-y)
(define-syntax (get stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ struct)

     (define struct-info (extract-struct-info (syntax-local-value #'struct)))
     (define accessors-list (map syntax-e  (fourth struct-info)))

     #``(#,@accessors-list)]))

(get point)
```

Using [`syntax-local-value`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._syntax-local-value%29%29), we can extract the value of the identifier bound by the pattern variable `struct`.

Using [`extract-struct-info`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structinfo.html?q=syntax-local#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstruct-info..rkt%29._extract-struct-info%29%29), we can extract the structure type information in a list form (it has 6 elements). From here the accessors list can be extracted (it's the fourth element in the list).

**Question**

How can I access the information about a struct (as shown in [Structure Type Transformer Binding](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/structinfo.html?q=syntax-local)) at the non-macro level? The two functions above cannot be used directly on structs outside a transformer because the struct is a procedure at that point (and `extract-struct-info` takes in a `struct-info`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `syntax-local-value` and `extract-struct-info` at run time. You must use run-time struct introspection instead.

If you make your struct transparent, like this:

```
(struct point [x y] #:transparent)
```

then you can get analogous values from a point instance using [`struct-info`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/inspectors.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._struct-info))) and [`struct-type-info`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/inspectors.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._struct-type-info))):

```
(define a-point (point 3 4))
(define-values (type skipped?) (struct-info a-point))
;; type = #<struct-type:point>, skipped = #f
(define-values (name inits autos acc mut imms super super-skipped?)
  (struct-type-info type))
(acc a-point 0) ;; => 3
```

The value of `type` above is the same as `struct:point` (implicitly defined by the struct definition), so if you know you're dealing with a point struct specifically, you coud use that instead. You still need `#:transparent` (or you need a sufficiently powerful inspector) to use `struct-type-info`, though.